# Is there a way to determine if a redirect occurrs during a WebRequest?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, httpwebrequest

I'm using HttpWebRequest to scrape Wikipedia.org. A lot of times there will be links to topics on a page that have been consolidated and therefore they redirect you to the correct page.

for example

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_prisoners_of_war_in_Soviet_Union_(after_1939)

redirects you to the correct topic which is

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_prisoners_of_war_in_the_Soviet_Union_(after_1939)

Notice the addition of the word "the".

I need to determine at this point whether or not a redirect has happened. Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I marked the response below as answered because technically that is how you tell if you have been redirected. The problem I am having is the Wikipedia is not actually doing a *hard redirect* with http response codes 3xx. They are doing *soft redirects* which serves up different content under the same Url. I'll have to find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(reponse.ResponseUri != request.RequestUri) {
    //You were redirected
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a property called "[AllowAutoRedirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx)" on the HttpWebRequest object.  If you turn that off you can follow the redirects yourself.

You could also try checking the HttpWebResponse.[ResponseUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.responseuri.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HttpWebRequest.Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.address.aspx) property, which is explicitly defined as "the URI after any redirections that happen during the request are complete"

Note that this should be used instead of the similar [HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.responseuri.aspx), as its documentation says:

> Applications that need to access the last redirected ResponseUri
>   should use the [HttpWebRequest..::..Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.address.aspx) property rather than
>   ResponseUri, since the use of ResponseUri property may open security
>   vulnerabilities.