# Check if redirected to default page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How to check using C# if "redirect" to "default document" happened?
For example, in browser I type URL: **mysite.com/**. When on server I check `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`, i receive **mysite.com/default.aspx**...

How I can get the exact URL that user has in his browser?
Thanks

**EDIT:** After some questions about the needs, I will give more details.
I have page with default.aspx with iframe inside of it. The iframe src is not the same origin (default.aspx is http and iframe content is https). On server side, i need to set the query string param to the src of iframe to include the exact URL that user has in browser. I need it in order to be able to set parent.location = parentURL + '#myparam' on iframe client side.
Currently everithing works fine, except when the request made to domain name without providing file name.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain if this answers your question as you probably don't want to handle the redirects yourself, but there is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014368/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-redirect-occurrs-during-a-webrequest

Comment: why would you want to check the redirection ?

Comment: @Turbot I added some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You typed
mysite.com/.

and you get
mysite.com/default.aspx...

Because you have set default.aspx as the default / Start up  page in your site. The browser always redirect to the default page. I think when we type `mysite.com` the asp.net automatically appends the default page in the URL, so when we use `Request.Url` we get the `mysite.com/default.aspx`

Comment: I don't think the browser redirects, since the URL in browser remains the same.

Comment: @AlexDn Sometimes URL remains same, like if we use Server.Transfer then URL remains same in the browser but page changed. Type `http://www.microsoft.com` or `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx` It will open the same page. If you only type '`http://www.microsoft.com` the asp.net will change the URL to this `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx`

Comment: And is it possible to get the ORIGINAL URL and not after asp.net modification?

Comment: @AlexDn Sorry,I don't know but May be if we try to get Request.URL in Application_BeginRequest in global.asax

Answer (score 0):

Try HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl

Comment: I think perhaps I haven't understood your question correctly. Under what circumstances might your users be redirected to the default document?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your intention of the `IFrame`, perhaps you are looking for Framset Script to determine the redirection ?

```
if (parent.location.href==window.location.href) 

    {
        // you re-direction codes...
    }
```

**EDIT :**
Giving a different **HTTP** and **HTTPS**, it's likely the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) kicked in. There is a workaround you could use `PostMessage` interface for cross sites.

Other option would be managed by Server(IIS) so that both http/https url request setting to default document , so that you don't need to alter client-side scripting for such complication handling.

Comment: When I trying to access parent.location.href, I receive error "Permission Denied" since parent is HTTP and window is HTTPS

Comment: are there from different domain ?

Comment: They are same domain, but different protocols

Comment: I already made it work by appending #data to parent.location, the only bug is with homepage, when no doc name provided. I used http://shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Blog/post/2009/08/17/Another-Cross-Domain-iFrame-Communication-Technique.aspx.

Answer (score -1):

You should delete `'Default.aspx' page` from your `IIS Default document list`. then you get exact URL that user entered.

Comment: When you do not enter any page name then IIS check page name in IIS Default document list. If page name exists in your solution then this page will be display. for ex. you setted default.aspx page in your IIS default document list.

Comment: But if I will delete it as you advice, so how then it will work??? I can't delete default document.